# SignalR hub check if a connection is still alive

Tags: signalr, signalr-hub, asp.net-core-signalr

We have a hub that manage clients like a chat.
On some occasions we have noticed that there are "dead" connections that no disconnect event has been invoked.
On ASP .NET framework 4.5.2 SignalR, we used `ITransportHeartbeat` to check the current connection state:

```
// SignalR connection state check - .NET framework 4.5.2
var heartBeat = GlobalHost.DependencyResolver.Resolve<ITransportHeartbeat>();
var connectionId = appConnection;
var connection = heartBeat.GetConnections().FirstOrDefault(
                                   c => c.ConnectionId == connectionId);

if (!connection.IsAlive)
{
     //...
}
```

I don't see `ITransportHeartbeat` anymore on SignalR .NET Core. Is there any way to find the current specific connection state?

Comment: Did you get an answer on this?  Seems crazy that this functionality could have been lost in the "upgrade".